# Close vote review queues are not functioning

Tags: bug, status-completed

The question titled, [How many names can a dolphin remember?](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/q/2/) has gotten a close vote which is more than enough to send it to the close vote review queue, however I don't see it in there. I have confirmed this in both regular and incognito browsing mode.

This was the same problem that happened on the last two private beta sites, so therefore I suggest an investigation.

Comment: Private beta runs in a special mode. I am just guessing: This could be the reason these review queues are not available? Maybe at this phase only Stack Exchange staff takes care of such tasks?

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong Yes private beta has its differences compare to public beta or graduated mode, but this behaviour is an unexpected one.

Comment: I only see 1 close vote and we need 5 to close a question. And since we get access to cast close votes are 15 rep most people have that perm so they cant flag questions to go into that queue.

Comment: But questions with an (at least 1) active close vote are also sent to the queue for review. (It doesn't matter if it's a close vote or flag it should be in there.) I did some personal testing and I have confirmed this.

Comment: Weird since in the help article it says

`The Close votes queue includes questions that other users have flagged as needing to be closed.`

Comment: @Ethan Also in the help center is this ["Any post which currently has an active **close vote** or a **close flag** will appear in the Close votes review queue."](https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) I understand the confusion.

Comment: Yep, that's broken but in a different way than last time, heh. Thanks for the report! I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

Fundamentally this turned out to be the [same problem as last time](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15/close-vote-reviews-are-not-triggered/57#57), but at least the root cause was different in this case. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Thanks again for the report. Scheduled routes should be running on Bioacoustics and its meta now, so you'll see the Close Votes queue populating as expected.